# jQuery .on() doubleclick pass data

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

When using:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '#selector_id', {form_key:10}, my_function)

my_function = function(){
    console.log(event)
}
```

I expect to be able to retrieve `form_key` from `event.data`, as per [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on).

However, under this situation I get a `MouseEvent`, rather than `Event`, and it does not have a `data` attribute.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the parameter you're trying to use, and it probably works:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '#selector_id', {form_key:10}, my_function)

function my_function(event){ // <- event
    console.log(event)
}
```

and remember that data passed is available in event.data, like:

```
event.data.form_key
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnvs8/)